# Set current_user in test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a test that looks like this:

```
test "should get create" do
   current_user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: 'not_saved_email@example.com')
   assert_difference('Inquiry.count') do
     post :create, FactoryGirl.build(:inquiry)
    end
    assert_not_nil assigns(:inquiry)
    assert_response :redirect
end
```

That's testing this part of the controller:

```
def create
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new(params[:inquiry])
    @inquiry.user_id = current_user.id
    if @inquiry.save
      flash[:success] = "Inquiry Saved"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

and the factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :inquiry do
    product_id 2
    description 'I have a question about....'
  end
end
```

but I keep getting errors in my tests:

```
      1) Error:
test_should_get_create(InquiriesControllerTest):
RuntimeError: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

What am I doing wrong? I need to set the current_user, and I believe I am in the test, but obviously, that's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things which come to mind:

`FactoryGirl.build(:user, ...)` returns unsaved instance of a user. I'd suggest to use `Factory.create` instead of it, because with unsaved instance there's no `id` and there's no way for (usually session based) `current_user` getter to load it from database. If you're using Devise, you should "sign in" user after creating it. This includes saving record in DB and putting reference to it into session. [See devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)

Also, passing ActiveRecord object to `create` action like this looks weird to me:

```
post :create, FactoryGirl.build(:inquiry)
```

Maybe there's some rails magic in play which recognizes your intent, but I'd suggest doing it explicitly:

```
post :create, :inquiry => FactoryGirl.build(:inquiry).attributes
```

or better yet, decouple it from factory (DRY and aesthetic principles in test code differ from application code):

```
post :create, :inquiry => {product_id: '2', description: 'I have a question about....'}
```

This references product with id = 2, unless your DB doesn't have FK reference constraints, product instance may need to be present in DB before action fires.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't create `current_user`. It was initialized only in `test` block.
There are two differents ways to do it:

First, use devise test helpers. Something like that

```
let(:curr_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, ...attrs...) }
sign_in curr_user
```

[devise doc](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29)

Second, you can stub `current_user` method in your controllers for test env

```
controller.stub(current_user: FactroryGirl.create(:user, ...attrs...))
```

And you should use `FactoryGirld.create(...)` instead of `FactoryGirl.build(...)`, because you factory objects have to be persisted.(be saved in db and has `id` attribute not nil)